# Accurate RF voltage magnitude measurement

Tags: voltage, voltage-measurement

How would you measure the magnitude of a RF sinewave in the KV, MHz  ballpark?

The frequency is known and the sinewave is very pure, does this help?

Can you devise a method that would give millivolt precision in a kilovolt?

Its also very desirable not to load the circuit too much.

How would your proposed precision method drift with temperature?

Comment: What's the application?

Comment: Mass Spec is where this could be handy

Comment: I've been involved in designing gas mass spectrometers and appreciate the kV necessity but the MHz side of things was never an issue so where does this bit come in?

Comment: The higher frequency gives better particle transmission and is workable only at modest masses .The low freq stuff is good for really high masses but the sensitivity of such a machine wont be very good .The MHz bit was a challenge.

Comment: Is there something that I can read as a background to using a high frequency source for mass spectrometry. It's been the early 90s since I was involved and although we were scanning through the molecular masses reasonably quickly it was still a DC source and a big magnet for curving the ions into a collector. Also, which parrt of the system are you trying to measure?

Comment: Sorry  the specs with big magnets can run DC .Newer types run RF and DC the DC is hundreds of volts at neglible current so measuring the RF is where its at.

Comment: Got a link to help me out?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31504/discussion-between-autistic-and-andy-aka).

Comment: I'd love to but I've got to go out but a link would really be cool.

Answer (score 2):

"Not loading too much" is vague : any estimate of the effective source impedance would help.

I would consider a parallel resonant circuit tuned to the known frequency : its impedance can be very high so it will not load a (steady state) sinewave source. (You did say high purity, so I'm presuming it's unmodulated).

Now you need a lower amplitude output to measure using conventional techniques. This could be a capacitive tap as user44635 suggested (the L simply resonates to tune out the capacitance) or a tap on the inductor, which will act as an autotransformer, transforming the impedance of your measurement system load by n^2.

edit : an inductor's *value* can drift with temperature (as can a capacitor's), but its turns ratio won't drift. This will affect the tuning frequency and that will have a quantifiable effect on the impedance (hence loading) at the frequency of interest, so this drift is a second order effect on accuracy. You'd need to calculate the loading effect as part of your error budget. Alternatively you could re-tune to find the peak, either periodically or for each measurement.

Clearly the turns ratio cannot drift : how accurately that translates to voltage ratio also depends on the coupling. I don't know how to put numbers on that, but if the secondary in a tap on the primary (autotransformer) I think it's pretty good.

ALTERNATIVE VIEW : do you need absolute accuracy or relative accuracy? It strikes me that most traditional techniques for precise measurement use differential techniques : between two arms of a Wheatstone bridge, or subtraction of a precision voltage (Daniell or Weston cell etc). If you had two nominally identical voltages (frequency and phase locked) can you measure the difference between them?

Comment: If the divider was resistive  megohms would be wanted so there wouldnt be excessive heating that could cause thermal drift.A capacitive divider would mean close tolerance caps in the low pF range .The inductor or transformer is yet another analog component that could drift.

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements are optimistic.

mV resolution at kV is possible, you just display a meaningless tail of noisy figures to the right of your display. Accuracy at kV is different, you would be lucky to see 10v accuracy in the best possible matched system.

A kV source would have humungeous power in a 50ohm impedance system. Therefore I can conclude it's in a high impedance system. Getting from there to a usable impedance will reduce accuracy.

'Not loading the circuit too much' will reduce accuracy. Especially if you are starting off with a high impedance system.

Being a very pure sinewave does not help. If your signal was buried in the noise, knowing the frequency and purity would help you reduce the noise by filtering. However, you are starting with a kV signal, so noise is not your problem.

With all those caveats, I would measure it by building a capacitive divider, say 1pF kV capacitor to the measurement terminal, 1nF to ground, giving a 1000:1 pot-down ratio. This 1nF source impedance then put into an oscilloscope. However, you will get only 100v accuracy with an oscilloscope, better if you can calibrate the scope with a known power source.

If you put the signal into an RF power meter, you can improve accuracy. However, these are all 50ohm input impedance. You could match from your 1nF to 50 ohms (which will reduce accuracy) and be frequency dependent.

Or you could build a pure resistive divider down to your power meter. The problem with this is whereas a 1pF capacitor is pretty much 'pure', especially at low frequencies like 1MHz, the required 10Mohm or higher resistor for the equivalent position is very much 'impure', and will have a significant stray shunt capacitance, which will have to be tuned out with the rest of your pot-down circuit, reducing accuracy.

Comment: good to see someone thinking about it . It aint easy !